# add value to integer[]

Tags: java, android, integer

I want to add a value to this integer

```
Integer[] nums = new Integer[] {1, 393993, 2918282}
```

I try to add values to this but the code be wrong, please give me the best way to do that

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: What's wrong about it? Does it give you an error? What is it? How are you trying to add values?

Comment: You want to add new element to array or you want to increment existing values by some value?

Comment: You are missing a `;`, it should be `Integer[] nums = new Integer[] {1, 393993, 2918282};`.

Comment: Integer[] nums = new Integer[] {1, 393993, 2918282};
/* code code..............*/
here a code to add a value to nums

Answer (score 4):

In Java, arrays have fixed size. So if you want a dynamic data structure, you should use classes from Java collections package.

For example, use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(393993);
intList.add(2918282);


// Then add value when you need it using .add() method
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you instantiate an array, you cannot add values to it; it becomes fixed in size. You're better off using something like `Java.Util.ArrayList` which supports adding items beyond its capacity.